# PHP get value showing .php from url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I've used a url rewrite in the htaccess file to show 2 query string values as /item1/item2

When I get item2 it has .php at the end. Is there something I'm missing on my rewrite?

Get call

```
$card = $_GET['card'];
$card; // This value has .php after the value
```

Rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^player-score\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  /player-score.php?id=$1&card=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Fully example URL

```
www.example.com/player-score.php?id=1&card=45
```

Comment: What is the complete url your typing in browser's location bar?

Comment: [www.example.com/player-score.php?id=1&card=45] and the card value shows 45.php

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I need to move the rule below underneath my query string rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^player-score/([^\/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$  /player-score.php?id=$1&card=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Are you using **.php** in the end /player_score/1/45.php?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. I have made minor edit to your rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^player-score/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$  player-score.php?id=$1&card=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```